# Multithread not finding first target function python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

So I have a peculiar situation where I'm multi-threading a set of functions with some of these calling further threads. In one such case, the first thread in a block of three fails to execute its target function and instead produces this error:

```
NameError: name '<FUNCTION_NAME>' is not defined
```

This is the code:

```
threadA = self.pool.apply_async(functionA)
threadB = self.pool.apply_async(functionB)
threadC = self.pool.apply_async(functionC)

valueA = threadA.get()
valueB = threadB.get()
valueC = threadC.get()
```

And the relevant function is defined above.

If I switch the order of these thread assignments, the first will produce the NameError. Eg. If threadB was assigned first, the error would be:

```
NameError: name 'functionB' is not defined
```

There's plenty of other threading going on while this is happening so I'm not sure if it's a resource issue.

**Edit:** 
I'm using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` not processes.

Any help would be great,

Cheers :)

Comment: `apply_async` is method of `multiprocessing.pool` so I guess your question is about processes not threads. Please, clarify. Probably the issue is connected with transferring global scope to subprocesses. Hard to say without the actual code.

Comment: You use `ThreadPool` - ok. What is structure of processes/threads then? Do you spawn new threads in the main process or subprocess? You start threads with `self.pool.apply_async` and the function name is `functionA`? Does not look like actual code you run. Rather some dummy lines. The truth is in the details of the implementation.

Comment: Spawn threads in main process @Poolka

Comment: My simple examples with `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` work just fine (python 3.6.8 / win10 x64). I get `NameError` only if I intentionally mess with imports or function names. I can hardly say more.